# I can't install blender on my hp desktop pc

Tags: installation

I am running  a 64 bit system with win 10 installed and up to date:

Blender 2.78 installs up to an almost finished point.. then an applet informs me .. that the blender file is too long for the start menu.

I am no dummy on a pc as I also code software and I've tried every trick I know  to get the program installed.

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Never heard that one before. What is the exact error message? You could also try the stand alone Blender version that can be run directly without installing. It is available on the blender.org download page when you click Other Versions and select the .ZIP one.

Comment: The message I get is that the file name is too long to go into program files and the start menu. I have tried installing an older version but get the same message

Comment: If you unzip the stand alone version then you can run it from anywhere, no installation required. If you open a command prompt and then run `echo %ProgramFiles%` do you get "C:\Program Files"?

Comment: Did you choose a custom install location? If so, try the standard location. It's a common "fake error", when NTFS decides that the path is too long for whatever reasons. Also, if it's only the start menu entry, you could create the link by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Switched off Microsoft Firewall and it downloaded straight away. Then switched Microsoft Firewall back on. Have firewall on router and Bitedefender antivirus, neither of which are that sensitive to other people's free software.

Answer (score -3):

Just tried it use the 32 bit that will work

Comment: Why should he use a 32bit software (aka dying breed) on a 64 operating system? Your answer doesn't solve anything.